# What are more advanced categorical encoding methods?

Tags: machine-learning, data, preprocessing, encoding

I'm familiar with the common methods:

- Label Encoding: `{A, B, C}` -> `[0, 1, 2]`
- One-Hot Encoding: `{A, B, C}` -> `[[1,0,0][0,1,0][0,0,1]]`

What other encoding methods exist and when would I need to use them over the two common methods?

Comment: There is also [Target encoding](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/targetencoder.html), but embedding sounds better\smarter. Which task do you want to solve using (un)supervised setup?

Answer (score 1):

Embeddings:

A --> [vector_A]
B --> [vector_B]
...

They are frequently used in neural networks to represent categorical values that can have a lot of different discrete values, like text. The vectors are obtained either in an ad-hoc previous training step or during the training of the model itself.

Comment: My understanding of embeddings is that they are lower dimensional transformations of higher-dimensional encodings e.g. a truncated PCA on a one-hot-encoded matrix. Is that right?

Comment: Well, they don't necessarily need to be of lower dimensionality, they just are learned representations in a continuous representation space. Also, I don't know if the one-hot + PCA  example is sound; normally, examples are trained so that "close" discrete values are close in the embedded space, for instance, skipgrams in text reflect the word co-occurrence statistics.